# How do make parts of echo not effected by pv

Tags: bash, echo, sh

I need help with this echo thing, I have a little thing called pv i use it to make it look like the text is being typed

```
echo "Cyan: What do you need" |pv -qL 10
```

I want Cyan: to not be effected by the pv -qL 10, but i don't know how to do that
and i want it all in the same line

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a sequential [command list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists):

```
echo -n 'Cyan: '; echo 'What do you need' |pv -qL 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to omit the newline that echo appends by default:

```
printf "Cyan: "
echo "What do you need" |pv -qL 10
```